# Adding blank page option via setAttribute in javascript

Tags: javascript

I can add an `a` element in js via this:

```
var mydiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var aTag = document.createElement('a');
aTag.setAttribute('href',"yourlink.htm");
aTag.innerHTML = "link text";
mydiv.appendChild(aTag);
```

But i want also make sure that this link opens in a new page. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
aTag.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/dWDAQ/

Comment: So it's that easy. Thanks (: